# Is There any way to convert a completed rig into a re-generatable python file?

Tags: python, rigging, constraints, blend-files, rigify

Currently Rigify allows for the regeneration of custom designed metarigs (Encode Metarig (or Sample) to Python). This is a GREAT time saver, but There seems to be no way as of yet to do the same with all the constraints to make the newly added metarigs/samples to work.